# Is it possible to overwrite a return pointer and jump directly to a function in another program that is already running on the same computer?

Tags: c, pointers, stack, buffer, overflow

I understand that a program can overwrite the return pointer to a different function in the same program running.

Hypothetically, if you knew the memory location of another function on a different program running on the same computer, could you access its function? It seems absurd, but I want to make sure I understand this situation.

FYI - I will be reading Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit.
http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

Comment: Each process has its own virtual address space.  Knowing the virtual address of a function in another process doesn't allow you to access it.

Comment: Not on any non-trivial OS or without explicit cooperation from the other process.

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot. Your operating system uses *virtual memory* to give each process its own *address space*. If something is has address 12345678 in your address space, you don't know what's at address 12345678 in another running program - it could be something entirely different or nothing.

And vice versa - if you know what's at address 87654321 in another program, that doesn't mean it's at address 87654321 in your program.